# How to tell if a web page has loaded with in a WebBrowser Control

Tags: windows, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I am trying to write a program that will tell my grandmother whether the internet is live or not. I know, I know, She just doesn't get it. So I want to create a program to load google.com or something and all I want the program to do is tell her whether the site was found or not. Is there a way to do this with the WebBrowser control?

I would really appreciate any help!

Thanks,
Cecil

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [`Ping` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx).

Call `Ping.Send("google.com")` and check whether `Status` is `Success`.

Comment: There are lots of ways to detect if the internet is available. This seems as good as any other.